# Representing $m\times n$ matrix using ordered $n$-tuples and an $m$-tuple

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Can a matrix, generally

\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} &\cdots   &a_{1,n} \\ 
 \vdots &\ddots   & \vdots \\ 
a_{m,1} &\cdots   &a_{m,n} 
\end{bmatrix} 
be represented using ordered $n$-tuples inside an $m$-tuple, like this:
$((a_{1,1},...,a_{1,n}),...,(a_{m,1},...,a_{m,n}))$ ?

Comment: The answer might depend on what exactly you mean by "represent", but the difference between your first way of arranging numbers and your second is really just notation.

Comment: @Constantine:we can represent matrix as a function $f:\mathbb N_m\times \mathbb N_n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(i,j)=a_{ij}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can express an $m\times n$ matrix using ordered $n$-tuples "inside" an (ordered) $m$-tuple, as you display. Sometimes this is referred to as expressing a matrix in *[row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)*. Similarly, one can express a matrix in *[column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)*.

Related to "column-major order" is the *[vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29)* of a matrix

Comment: Nice links and write up! +1

Comment: I am going to go to the uni. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: I need to do that too! I miss the wonderful library and need to look up about 100 things! ;-) Hope all is well my friend!

Answer (score 1):

humm .yes we can write as a block matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} &\cdots   &a_{1,n} \\ 
 \vdots &\ddots   & \vdots \\ 
a_{m,1} &\cdots   &a_{m,n} 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
[a_{1,1} &\cdots   &a_{1,n} ]\\ 
  \vdots &\ddots   & \vdots \\ 
[a_{m,1} &\cdots   &a_{m,n}] 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a^1  \\ 
 a^2 \\ 
.\\
.\\
a^m  & 
\end{bmatrix}$$ such that $a^i$ is $i-th$ row

Comment: @Software:thanks Software you are very kindly